# Windows Phone app submission in not OS supported language

Tags: windows-phone-7

I've made an app which content is in Armenian language and not natively supported in the Windows Phone OS. The app is a blog reader which read RSS feed for posts and shows that posts in the mobile app. Posts in blog is only in Armenian and there is no translated version to English or any other language. The neutral language for assembly is set to English. The app long description for marketplace is in English and also I clearly mentioned what content of app is in Armenian language. But app certification is failed. Here is comments from the certification test results .pdf file.

> The application's long description and/or UI content is
>   presented in Armenian not natively supported in the OS.  For an
>   application to be presented in a language not natively supported in
>   the OS, its description must satisfy the following  requirements:
>
> 1. A statement to indicate the application is not in the targeted language.
> 2. A full description text in the targeted language.
> 3. A full description text in the language supported by the application.

As I understand from the comments I provided first two points and the only reason of certification failure is the 3rd point - a description in a Armenian language which was not exist in description.

So what I must to do? Provide long description in Armenian language also and it's all? Or in any way it will fail the certification.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you must provide two long descriptions:

one in targeted language

one in language that is set in app properties

Comment: You right. I just now received the message what app has passed the testing and going to be published.